# script to open terminal, run command and keep terminal open

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have simple goal of creating script to open terminal, run command and then keep terminal open.

Here is what I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

xterm -e -hold ls
```

It generates the following error:

```
xterm: Can't execvp -hold: No such file or directory
```

Then I also tried

```
 #!/bin/bash

   konsole -e --noclose ls
```

This simple does not do anything, when I double-click it. (I made sure that script file is executable)

I do not want to use `gnome-terminal` as it requires creating profile for `gnome-terminal` first.

Would it be easier to do in python?

Comment: In your first command I think `hold` is considered as a file or directory.

Comment: @Rahul thank you, do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument after `-e` is taken as a command to be executed. So for xterm, this works:

```
xterm -hold -e ls
```

I don't have Konsole installed, but this should work:

```
konsole --noclose -e ls
```

Comment: I know it's been a while, and I've started my own thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1210190/one-click-open-terminal-run-commands-keep-using-the-terminal?noredirect=1&lq=1), but this does not make the terminal interactive. No further commands can be run after the terminal opens. How can you make the terminal interactive?

Answer (score 2):

From `man xterm`

```
The  -ls  flag and the loginShell resource are ignored if -e is
               also given
```

That's why you got error in your first command.

This command worked for me.

```
xterm -hold ls
```