# One-click: Open terminal, run commands, keep using the terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, konsole

I need a bash script that does the following:

1. open a new terminal
2. change to a specific directory
3. run a command in that directory
4. keep the terminal open for further use

Specifically I want to:

1. open the konsole terminal
2. change to `/my/work/dir/`
3. inside `/my/work/dir/`, run `source bin/activate`
4. after that I need to run further commands inside `/my/work/dir/`, e.g. `ls`

A [very similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/928536/script-to-open-terminal-run-command-and-keep-terminal-open) was given the following answer for the script (adapted to my requirements):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
konsole --noclose --workdir /my/work/dir/ -e 'bash -c 'source bin/activate''
```

This does open a new terminal inside `/my/work/dir/`, but the terminal is not interactive. The

`user@userMachine: /my/work/dir$`

is missing that allows me to run further commands and anything I type (e.g. `pwd`) returns nothing, just new lines.

Comment: Shells like bash have the concept of rcfiles, which are essentially sourced at the start of the shell session. Could you accomplish what you want by defining a custom rcfile and creating a konsole profile that triggers the shell with that rcfile?

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify what the terminal to do after executing the command `source bin/activate`. You want an active bash session so you need to run `bash`. In addition there is a mes with the quotes. So the script could be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
konsole --noclose --workdir /my/work/dir/ -e 'bash -c "source bin/activate; exec bash"' &
```

- `&` at the end is added in order to keep the *main* terminal usable, in case you are executing that script from other terminal window.
- the `exec` command could be omitted, and you can use only `bash`.

Here are few answers of similar questions, dedicated to `gnome-terminal`:

- [how can I open a extra console and run a program in it with one command?](https://askubuntu.com/q/974756/566421)
- [Open a new terminal and source scripts](https://askubuntu.com/q/965828/566421)
- [How to open one (or more) gnome-terminal window with few tabs, each with different profile, when start/reboot the computer?](https://askubuntu.com/q/953021/566421)

Comment: Ok This shows some strange behaviour now: The terminal opens in the correct directory. Also the virtualenv seems to be running, since `pip freeze` gives only the packages installed in the virtualenv. But when I then try to `$ deactivate` i get `deactivate: command not found`. I then activate again (again pip freeze gives correct output), then deactivate, and now `pip freeze` STILL gives the environment packages, not the system wide packages as expected...

Comment: Hello, @DouglasJamesBock, I really do not have an idea how your environment is setup and what `bin/activate` actually does. Try to change the shebang of the script to `#!/bin/bash` and/or `source` also the `$HOME/.bashrc` file probably some paths are loaded by this file.

Comment: the `source bin/activate` activates the [python virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) I previously created in `my/work/dir`. I have also tried your other suggestions without improvements. I can not even `exit` the terminal, I guess due to the `--noclose`. I'm starting to think that Konsole might be to limited for this.

Comment: @DouglasJamesBock: Please tray with some other terminal emulator, `gnomen-terminal` I would say - check the references given in the answer.

Comment: There is any difference if `source bin/activate && exec bash` is used instead of `source bin/activate; exec bash` ?

Comment: Hello, @funder7, please check this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1182653/566421 IMO, there is not difference in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I am not able to comment, but from what I understand I may suggest

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /my/work/dir/
source bin/activate
konsole
```

Comment: This would make the most sense to me!  Set up the environment, then launch konsole with the environment set.

Comment: This gives the same issues as my first comment under pa4080's answer.