# How do I create a Script to open a new terminal and execute a command?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, gnome-terminal

I have tried this for my Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
gnome-terminal -- cd Server
gnome-terminal -- ./start.sh
```

However when I run it I get this error:

It also opens two terminals when I just want one with two commands.

**There was an error creating the child process for this terminal**

**Failed to execute child process “cd” (No such file or directory)**

How do I get the commands to run correctly?

I am on Ubuntu 19.04 and a complete newbie.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [script to open terminal, run command and keep terminal open](https://askubuntu.com/questions/928536/script-to-open-terminal-run-command-and-keep-terminal-open) Also, 19.04 went EoL in January, and is no longer supported.

Answer (score 5):

`cd` is a shell builtin command - you can't execute it directly in a terminal, it needs a shell.

So for example

```
gnome-terminal -- sh -c 'cd Server && ./start.sh'
```

(you may need to give an absolute `/path/to/Server` depending on where you are running the command from).

Comment: Thank you very much! This did the trick. ;)